# Android Studio. Calling Static method from other Activity

Tags: java, android-studio, methods, static

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static  final int REQUEST_LOCATION=1;

    public static Context gb;

    static LocationManager locationManager;
    public static String latitude,longitude;
    public MainActivity(Context context){
        this.gb = context;
    }


    Button getlocationBtn;
    static TextView showLocationTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Add permission

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        showLocationTxt=findViewById(R.id.show_location);
        getlocationBtn=findViewById(R.id.getLocation);

        getlocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //place the following line on all operations e.g click
                locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                //Check gps is enable or not

                if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                {
                    //Write Function To enable gps

                    OnGPS();
                }
                else
                {
                    //GPS is already On then

                    getLocation();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public static void getLocation() {

        //Check Permissions again

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(gb,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(gb, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)gb,new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        else
        {
            Location LocationGps= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Location LocationNetwork=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Location LocationPassive=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            if (LocationGps !=null)
            {
                double lat=LocationGps.getLatitude();
                double longi=LocationGps.getLongitude();

                latitude=String.valueOf(lat);
                longitude=String.valueOf(longi);

                showLocationTxt.setText("Your Location:"+"\n"+"Latitude= "+latitude+"\n"+"Longitude= "+longitude);
            }
            else if (LocationNetwork !=null)
            {
                double lat=LocationNetwork.getLatitude();
                double longi=LocationNetwork.getLongitude();

                latitude=String.valueOf(lat);
                longitude=String.valueOf(longi);

                showLocationTxt.setText("Your Location:"+"\n"+"Latitude= "+latitude+"\n"+"Longitude= "+longitude);
            }
            else if (LocationPassive !=null)
            {
                double lat=LocationPassive.getLatitude();
                double longi=LocationPassive.getLongitude();

                latitude=String.valueOf(lat);
                longitude=String.valueOf(longi);

                showLocationTxt.setText("Your Location:"+"\n"+"Latitude= "+latitude+"\n"+"Longitude= "+longitude);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(gb, "Can't Get Your Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }

    private void OnGPS() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage("Enable GPS").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

==================== Calling Activity==============================

```
package com.example.currentlocation;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class calling extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnLoc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calling);
        btnLoc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getLocation);
        btnLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.getLocation();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

===============================Question================================

Greetings! I am trying to write a code in java. I want to declare all of the methods in a single class with static modifier. So that whenever required I could call that method and perform function associated with that. in the given example I am trying to toast the current location which is working perfectly fine on button click. but when I try to call this static getLocation from another activity the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with this, UI elements like the TextView, shouldn’t be static. If you want to modularise functions, you are better off writing Utils classes. Don’t try to access methods from other activities, even though it is possible to access non static methods, if you instantiate that particular Activity class. Static methods are almost useless in an Activity.

The Android system instantiates the Activities and calls the life cycle methods, to display and store info for that screen. Activities are not meant to be used as conventional classes. I would suggest studying the MVC architecture and Android activity life cycle.